# How to refine ambiguous tense reference?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, tenses, past-tense

> Caught offguard, Gibbet retreated to the safety of the wall, fervently hoping that the darkness was sufficient to hide him from her gaze.

Reading this sentence, it feels ambiguous (to me) whether it is referring to -

1. Gibbet hoping that the darkness was sufficient enough that he was not already seen.
2. Gibbet hoping that the darkness is sufficient enough to keep him hidden.

What can be done to clarify that #1 is the correct intention ? I have considered using "had been" but that does not seem to make much of a difference (Do let me know if my notion is wrong). I think it is the "hoping" which is messing up the interpretation.

Comment: "Had been" makes interpretation (1) unambiguous: the past perfect has to refer to a time or an event *before* the main action of the sentence.

Comment: @ConnorHarris: "hoping that the darkness had been sufficient to hide him from her gaze" - doesn't that sound like wishful thinking ? That he thinks the darkness is not enough and he wishes it was sufficient enough.

Comment: If he was hoping one, he was hoping the other, and even making sense of the distinction is hard, let alone conveying it in one clause.

Comment: @JohnLawler The distinction seems clear to me: "had been" means that at the time of the sentence, Gibbet fears that he has *already* been seen at some previous moment, whereas "was" means that he's trying not to be seen at the time of the sentence. It's hard to tell which is better without more context, though.

Comment: If I were trying to convey non-ambiguously that he was hoping that the place to which he was then moving was specifically \*from that point (going to be, upon reaching position)\* sufficient to keep him hidden, then I would be inclined to use ‘would be’ in place of ‘was’ in the phrase “[…], fervently hoping that the darkness *would be* sufficient to hide him from her gaze”.

Comment: Backshifting is mandatory in narration. Putting *is* there is ungrammatical.